# Saving localstorage key into MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, local-storage

We have a small competition in my town where we need to store localstorage keys into MySQL using Ajax.

By doing this project, I found few problems.

This is my localstorage key and value:

Key: `BM`

Value:

```
 [{"id":"item-1","icon":"google.com"},
    {"id":"item-3","icon":"tumblr.com"},
    {"id":"item-5","icon":"youtube.com"}]
```

So basically its **id: ID, icon: URL** and both can be random.

When I store this into MySQL using Ajax, the value changes to:

```
[{\"id\":\"item-1\",\"icon\":\"google.com\"},
{\"id\":\"item-3\",\"icon\":\"tumblr.com\"},
{\"id\":\"item-5\",\"icon\":\"youtube.com\"}]
```

The structure of that row is longtext. I've tried plain text but is the same.

Id like to hear other thoughts from more experienced developers how would you do it.

The localstorage value added and parsed with JSON.

Comment: The change is due to MySQL escaping the " - why it's a problem? You can work around it by replacing \" with " in your client.

Comment: It is safe to do thought? My question was if my entire method is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like php is adding slashes to your input before you insert your data. This could be caused by magicquotes. Have a look at: http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php

If this is the case, the solution is to either turn off magicquotes in php or to use `stripslashes()`

```
<?php

// Assuming your input is in the input variable
$input = stripslashes($_GET['input']);

mysql_query("insert into `table` ( `columnname` ) values( '" . mysql_real_escape_string($input) . "' )");

?>
```

Comment: Actually, I could be wrong. I'm not sure if magicquotes escapes double quotes. Can anyone verify?

Comment: At the moment I am using mysql_real_escape_string() instead

Comment: The dreaded [Magic Quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.what.php) would have that effect but in this case it is your use of mysql_real_escape_string(). You can either use [stripslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) when retrieving from the db or switch to prepared statements.